# Can iPhone app revenue be split between multiple bank accounts?

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect

Under a corporate apple developer account, is it possible to add more than one bank account to a given paid app and specify which percentage of the commission Apple will pay out the commissions? I'm asking because I'm developing an app with a partner, and we've agreed to split the commissions, so this kind of setup would be easy & convenient.

Thanks!

Matt

Comment: You should be asking Apple about this, not SO.

Comment: Hi MattDiPasquale, did you found a solution to this. Please share. Thanks.

Comment: @AlejandroDavidCotillaRojas no, I did not.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can’t configure iTunes Connect this way, so the answer is likely “no,” but you can always e-mail Apple’s Developer Support team.

Comment: So, from iTunes Connect, you can only add one bank account? How do you suggest going about automatically splitting up the commissions?

Comment: Given that you can only get paid at *most* once a month, this is something that may have to be done manually. I’m not aware of any software solution.

Comment: @MattDiPasquale : If you don't trust anyone to split up the income to the account on iTunes Connect and pay out the correct fractions to the appropriate parties, you will have to pay to automate the process yourself, by hiring an accountant, bonded bookkeeper, or some-such, to do it for you.